# jQuery Fullscreen error

Tags: jquery, html, html5-video

I am building a HTML5 video player but can't get the fullscreen to work, my code is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var videoPlayer = $('#video-player');
  $('.btnFullscreen').on('click', function(){
   videoPlayer[0].RequestFullScreen();
   return false;
  });
 });
```

I get the following error:

> videoPlayer[0].RequestFullScreen is not a function

I have also tried specific browser versions e.g. webkitEnterFullscreen and MozRequestFullscreen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You typed it wrong, change it from

```
videoPlayer[0].RequestFullScreen();
```

to

```
videoPlayer[0].requestFullscreen();
```

for different browser support, you can use the solution from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Using_full_screen_mode)

```
if (elem.requestFullscreen) {
  elem.requestFullscreen();
} else if (elem.msRequestFullscreen) {
  elem.msRequestFullscreen();
} else if (elem.mozRequestFullScreen) {
  elem.mozRequestFullScreen();
} else if (elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
  elem.webkitRequestFullscreen();
}
```

Comment: still same error, I am testing on Firefox 30.0 on localhost and on a live server

Comment: Solved mine too, but not ONE of the 4 options worked by itself and that has me confused. (I would have expected webkit to be the one I needed).

Comment: @KAS - All modern browsers should be using `requestFullscreen` now, without any prefixes, but not too long ago they all used prefixes, so to support as many browsers as possible, it's still not a bad idea to just them all, like in the answer.